# Tabulator table does not get resized after the window resolution changes

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have a tabulator table. I have added a listener to watch resize event of window.
Inside the resize event, I have table.redraw(true)
The code is hit when the resolution is changed.Although the tabulator is redrawn, it never is properly aligned. Few columns are hidden. But if I refresh the page, the table gets drawn properly.
I do not want to add refresh everytime the resolution changes. Is there anyother option that I can try?

```js
this.myTable = new Tabulator("#myTab", {
    layout:"fitColumns",      //fit columns to width of table
    data: this.tableData,
    columns:this.columns,
    maxHeight:"100%",
    autoResize:true,
    resizableColumns:false,
    resizableRows:false, 
    responsiveLayout:true,  //hide columns that dont fit on the table
    tooltips:true,            //show tool tips on cells
    addRowPos:"top",          //when adding a new row, add it to the top of the table
    history:true,             //allow undo and redo actions on the table
    pagination:"local",       //paginate the data
    paginationSize:10,         //allow 7 rows per page of data
    movableColumns:true, 
    initialSort:[             //set the initial sort order of the data
        {column:"name", dir:"asc"}
    ]
});

window.addEventListener('resize',(event)=>{                
    this.myTable.redraw(true);
});
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a JS Fiddle or Code pen that demonstrates your issue, it is hard to offer advice without seeing the environment in which your table is setup

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add a setTimeout to your redraw function if the page needs some time to settle down after the resolution change:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    table.redraw(true);
}, 500);
```